# Ice throw from industrial wind turbine

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

I was watching a documentary where the residents didn't want to have a wind turbine erected nearby. One of the comments from the company was that an ice throw would have very little importance since it would not travel far from the tower.

```
Description of turbine:
400 foot tower
150 ft length of blade
175 mph tip speed
```

I converted into SI units and calculated a worst case throw of 700 m (without any air resistance).

My question: how far would the ice go with air resistance? Assume a football shape of 1 kg. What is the final velocity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mathematica, assuming a spherical ball of ice with a rough surface (so that drag coefficient is 1), the position as a function of time in meters is:

```
m = 1;(*Mass in kg*)
\[Rho] = 1.2;(*Density of air in kg/m^3*)
A = 0.012;(*Projected area of ice sphere in m^2*)
Cd = \
1;(*Conservative estimate of 1, might be lower*)
g = 9.81;(*Gravity \
acceleration in m/s^2*)
eqn = 
 Thread[m {x''[t], 
     y''[t]} == -(1/
      2) \[Rho] A Cd Sqrt[{x'[t], y'[t]}.{x'[t], y'[t]}] {x'[t], 
      y'[t]} - {0, g}];(*Equation of motion*)
IC = 
 Thread[{x[0], y[0], x'[0], y'[0]} == {0, 120, 75/Sqrt[2], 75/Sqrt[
    2]}];(*Initial height of 120m and initial speed 75m/s*)
L = 11;
s = NDSolve[eqn && IC, {x, y}, {t, 0, L}]
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, L}, PlotLabel -> "x (red) and y (blue)", PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

> [image]

Repeating with drag coefficient 0.42:

> [image]

And with no drag:

> [image]

So it could travel between 150 and 300 meters, assuming it was ejected at 75 m/s at a 45 degree angle from an initial height of 120m.

Comment: Something doesn't add up. I got 700 m without drag, you got 300 m. What is the scale on the x-axis?

Comment: @LDC3 he has time (in seconds) on the x-axis and position (in meters) on the y-axis, for both the vertical and horizontal motion. You are interested in the y value of the red line when the blue line crosses the x-axis. Regarding the computation I would increase the initial height to ~150m (pole+wing), moreover in presence of drag the optimum angles is below 45°. Playing a bit with the parameters I went up to ~350m with a drag coefficient of 0.5

Comment: @LDC3: No, I also got 700m without drag (300m was with drag). The $x$-axis is in red, and in the third picture (the simulation without drag) the red curve goes up to 700m.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to duplicate your work on a spreadsheet. Here is my result:
[image: Trajectory of ice thrown from a turbine]

Comment: That's a nice shape. You can see the air changing the parabola in the correct manner.